# Linq to sql/xml , to object ,and to dataset comparison

Tags: linq

Hellow Dears,
i read deeply in LinQ articles and i wonder about one thing not got it is what difference between LinQ Types [To SQL/XML -  To Object - To DataSet].
need simple clarify comparison specially for memory view

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Linq" stands for "Langage Integrated Query" --- basically, it means that the query syntax keywords (`from` `where` `select` etc) are now officially part of the language.

Now, at the highest level, a query against an array or a database table is doing essentially the same thing --- but the actual mechanics of how the query happens are quite different.

Linq2Sql, Linq2Object et al, are different subsystems which allow very different queries to be expressed using a common syntax.